# How to rewrite a makefile to distutils.core.Extension

Tags: python, cython, distutils

I have the following makefile:

```
g++ -o OUTPUT runner.cpp main.cpp src/file1.cpp  src/file2.cpp  

-L/usr/local/cpp_gpu/lib 
-lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_cudabgsegm -lopencv_cudafeatures2d -lopencv_cudaobjdetect -lopencv_cudastereo -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_intensity_transform -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_mcc -lopencv_quality -lopencv_rapid -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_superres -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_plot -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_cudaoptflow -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_cudalegacy -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_cudawarping -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_ml -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_cudaimgproc -lopencv_cudafilters -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_cudaarithm -lopencv_core -lopencv_cudev -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt 

-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 
-lcudart -lnppc -lnppial -lnppicc -lnppicom -lnppidei -lnppif -lnppig -lnppim -lnppist -lnppisu -lnppitc -lnpps -lcublas -lcudnn -lcufft 

-I/usr/local/cpp_gpu/include/opencv4
```

I want to rewrite this to a Extension of distutils.core so that it later on can be used in a Cython setup. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension) is a little unclear about how I should do this. This is what I got thus far (in setup.py).

```
includes_dirs = [numpy.get_include(), '/usr/local/cpp_gpu/lib', '/usr/local/cuda/lib64']
library_dirs = ['/usr/local/cpp_gpu/include/opencv4']
args = ['-Wno-cpp']
files = ["src/file1.cpp", "src/file2.cpp", "main.cpp", "OUTPUT.pyx"]
libraries = ['opencv_gapi', 'opencv_stitching', 'opencv_aruco', 'opencv_bgsegm', 'opencv_bioinspired', 'opencv_ccalib',
             'opencv_cudabgsegm', 'opencv_cudafeatures2d', 'opencv_cudaobjdetect', 'opencv_cudastereo', 'opencv_dnn_objdetect',
             'opencv_dnn_superres', 'opencv_dpm', 'opencv_face', 'opencv_freetype', 'opencv_fuzzy', 'opencv_hdf', 'opencv_hfs',
             'opencv_img_hash', 'opencv_intensity_transform', 'opencv_line_descriptor', 'opencv_mcc', 'opencv_quality',
             'opencv_rapid', 'opencv_reg', 'opencv_rgbd', 'opencv_saliency', 'opencv_stereo', 'opencv_structured_light',
             'opencv_phase_unwrapping', 'opencv_superres', 'opencv_surface_matching', 'opencv_tracking', 'opencv_highgui',
             'opencv_datasets', 'opencv_text', 'opencv_plot', 'opencv_videostab', 'opencv_cudaoptflow', 'opencv_optflow',
             'opencv_cudalegacy', 'opencv_videoio', 'opencv_cudawarping', 'opencv_xfeatures2d', 'opencv_shape', 'opencv_ml',
             'opencv_ximgproc', 'opencv_video', 'opencv_dnn', 'opencv_xobjdetect', 'opencv_objdetect', 'opencv_calib3d',
             'opencv_imgcodecs', 'opencv_features2d', 'opencv_flann', 'opencv_xphoto', 'opencv_photo', 'opencv_cudaimgproc',
             'opencv_cudafilters', 'opencv_imgproc', 'opencv_cudaarithm', 'opencv_core', 'opencv_cudev', 'dl', 'm', 'pthread', 'rt']

libraries += ['cudart', 'nppc', 'nppial', 'nppicc', 'nppicom', 'nppidei', 'nppif', 'nppig', 'nppim', 'nppist', 'nppisu',
              'nppitc', 'npps', 'cublas', 'cudnn', 'cufft ']

ext_modules = [Extension(
    "OUTPUT",
    files,
    language='c++',
    include_dirs=includes_dirs,
    library_dirs=library_dirs,
    extra_compile_args=args,
    libraries=libraries
)]
```

The compilation however fails with the error message (works fine if used with the makefile):

```
src/file1.hpp:7:34: fatal error: opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem the include dirs and library dirs should be switched:

```
includes_dirs = [numpy.get_include(), '/usr/local/cpp_gpu/include/opencv4']
library_dirs = ['/usr/local/cpp_gpu/lib', '/usr/local/cuda/lib64']
```